# On-Premises Hosting of Trained DeepAR Model built on AWS SageMaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I have started working with **AWS SageMaker** recently with the examples provided by AWS. I used this [example](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/introduction_to_amazon_algorithms/deepar_electricity/DeepAR-Electricity.ipynb) (**DeepAR** Model) in order to forecast a time series. After training, a model artifacts file has been created in my S3 bucket.

**My question:** Is there a way to host that trained model in a own hosting environment? (client premises)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except SageMaker XGBoost, SageMaker built-in algorithms are not designed to be used out of Amazon. That does not mean that it's impossible, for example you can find here and there snippets peeking inside model artifacts (eg for [Factorization Machines](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/extending-amazon-sagemaker-factorization-machines-algorithm-to-predict-top-x-recommendations/) and [Neural Topic Model](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/introduction_to_applying_machine_learning/ntm_20newsgroups_topic_modeling/ntm_20newsgroups_topic_model.ipynb)) but these things can be hacky and are usually not part of official service features. Regarding DeepAR specifically, the model was open-sourced couple weeks ago as part of `gluon-ts` python package ([blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/gluon-time-series-open-source-time-series-modeling-toolkit/), [code](https://gluon-ts.mxnet.io/)) so if you develop a model specifically for your own hosting environment I'd recommend to use that gluon-ts code in the MXNet container, so that you'll be able to open and read the artifact out of SageMaker.

Comment: Thank you @Oliver_Cruchant! Another question: can you please recommend any guide for MXNet container usage and deployment?

Comment: sure! this example is very similar to what you would need to do https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker-python-sdk/mxnet_gluon_mnist/mxnet_mnist_with_gluon.ipynb. full SDK documentation is here https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using_mxnet.html. If you don't want to deploy in SageMaker, your setup is quite simple: you just need a data loading piece, then model fitting and saving the model at opt/ml/model for copy of the artifact to s3.